# Query datetime field with only date in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

In my table, I have a datetime column with format Y/m/d H:m:s (ex: 2019/07/31 09:10:50).

In my blade view, I have a date picker to choose date with format Y/m/d.

Now I want to query select data with that date picker variable. (ex: I choose 2019/7/31, it will select from 2019/7/31 00:00:00 to 2019/7/31 23:59:59).

Here is my eloquent query:

```
public function getFilterUserActivity($filterFrom, $filterTo)
{
    return $this->select(
                        'user.fullname',
                        'user.email',
                        "{$this->table}.id",
                        "{$this->table}.user_id",
                        "{$this->table}.name",
                        "{$this->table}.distance",
                        "{$this->table}.moving_time",
                        "{$this->table}.pace",
                        "{$this->table}.type",
                        "{$this->table}.start_date_local",
                        "{$this->table}.max_speed",
                        "{$this->table}.average_speed",
                        "{$this->table}.is_valid",
                        "{$this->table}.invalid_description"
                        )
                ->join('user', 'user.id', '=', "{$this->table}.user_id")
                ->join('department', 'department.id', '=', 'user.department_id')
                ->where("{$this->table}.max_speed", '>=', 7)
                ->whereBetween("{$this->table}.created_at",[$filterFrom, $filterTo])
                ->paginate(15);
```

And here is my date variable request from view:

```
$filter = $request->input('date-filter'); //2019/7/31
```

I think I should convert this $filter variable into two variable which are $filterFrom = 2019/7/31 00:00:00 and $filterTo = 2019/7/31 23:59:59 and pass to query function.

Is it possible?

Can you help me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this ...

`$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '2009-02-15');`

`echo "Format: $format; " . $date->format('Y/m/d H:i:s') . "\n";`

and you can set the time after day

`$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '2009-02-15');`

`echo "Format: $filterFrom; " . $date->format('Y/m/d 00:00:00') . "\n";`

`echo "Format:   $filterTo; " . $date->format('Y/m/d 23:59:59') . "\n";`

Comment: what is $format? I got error Undefined variable: format

Comment: ok I understood it, I have to set my date format into $format, it's worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

in native php code, you can do like this

```
$radical = $request->input('date-filter')
$filterFrom = date_create_from_format("Y/m/d H:m:i",strtotime("$radical 00:00:00"))->getTimestamp(); 
$filterTo = date_create_from_format("Y/m/d H:m:i",strtotime("$radical 23:59:59"))->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: I got error Call to a member function getTimestamp() on bool

Comment: I pass wrong date format into it. I fixed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) package in laravel for determining the start and end of day. Check the documentation for more information regarding the package. I think this'll solve your problem as we'll be fetching the start of day and end of day using the startOfDay and endOfDay but you need to parse the raw string date to Carbon object.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$date = Carbon::parse($request->input('date-filter')); // 2019/7/31
$dateFrom = $date->startOfDay(); // 2019/7/31 00:00:00
$dateTo = $date->endOfDay(); // 2019/7/31 23:59:59
```

Comment: My result is null. I debug my $dateFrom variable and see 2019-07-26 23:59:59.999999 UTC (+00:00), maybe it's not like my column format, there is only Y-m-d H:m:s

Comment: If you still want to use the Carbon, you might need also to format it by passing another argument. e.g. $dateTo = $date->endOfDay()->format('Y/m/d H:m:i');